# Recolher menu dropdown com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu fiz o seguinte código em JavaScript, para ele expandir o dropdown, mas agora não sei como faço para ele recolher o menu, eu queria que quando o "Focus" não fosse no link, ele recolhesse (ex: clicando fora do alcance do menu):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').click(function() {
        $('li.active').removeClass("active"); //aqui removemos a class do item anteriormente clicado para que possamos adicionar ao item clicado
        $(this).addClass("active"); //aqui adicionamos a class ao item clicado
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0mb26qf/1/)

Comment: Você pode usar o `.mouseleave` na `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No teu código faz assim:

Passa como parâmetro o *event* na função click do `li` e adiciona os métodos `preventDefault` e `stopPropagation`.

**Exemplo**

Dê um nome absoluto ao menu:

```
<ul class="main-menu">
```

Especifique melhor para quem é o click:

```
$('.main-menu > li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
```

> Nota: a expressão `.main-menu > li` significa que o segundo elemento tem que ser
>   filho direto do primeiro

E adicione o seguinte evento no `html, body`

```
$("html, body").click(function(event) {
    $('.main-menu > li.active').removeClass("active");
});
```

Agora sempre que o clique não for em `.main-menu > li` ou em seus filhos, a classe `active` será removida dos elementos `.main-menu > li`.

---

### [Atualizado JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0mb26qf/7/)

**Nota: não coloque `preventDefault` nem `stopPropagation` no evento do `body`, senão dará problema nos eventos padrões, por exemplo de botões ou *links***

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo, mas assim, quando eu clico no sub-menu ele fecha também, tem como manter ele aberto?

Comment: Tem sim, é só você remover ou comentar a linha `$('li.active').removeClass("active");` no evento do click.

Comment: Atualizei ali o JSFiddle, da uma olhada. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo que você use o evento `mouseleave` para controlar tal comportamento, assim:

```
$(function() {
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

    $('li').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Lembrando que você precisa sair da área do `li`.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m0mb26qf/6/)

Comment: Gostei do seu código, mas como vou usar ele para touch também, preciso de algo que tenha a ver com o click, pode ser clicando novamente no link.

Comment: Editei minha resposta para que o clique exiba/esconda. Apenas substituí o `addClass` do event delegate `click` por `toggleClass`, que verifica se a classe está presente e a remove, e vice/versa.